# Problemas com consulta Lambda e DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime, expressões-lambda

Ola tenho o seguinte código ActionResult da minha controller abaixo:

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizedUser]
public ActionResult Load(DateTime DataInicial, DateTime DataFinal)
{
    var AcessoDominio = new SmartAdmin.Domain.Acesso();
    var Collection = new List<AcessoDto>();

    Collection = AcessoDominio.GetList(_ => _.DTH_ACESSO >= DataInicial &&
                                                _.DTH_ACESSO <= DataFinal)
                                                 .OrderByDescending(_ => _.DTH_ACESSO)
    .ToList();

    ViewBag.DataInicial = DataInicial;
    ViewBag.DataFinal = DataFinal;

    return View("Index", Collection.ToPagedList(1, PageSize));
}
```

Quando do um submit na pagina de duas datas por exemplo 22/09/2015 e 22/09/2015
respectivas Data Inicial e Data Final minha consulta não retorna nada e quando
mudo a consulta para  `22/09/2015` e `23/09/2015` retorna somente itens do dia `22`.

O que eu precisaria é consultar é as data no between e tambem por hora a query que é gerada pelo Entity é a seguinte :

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`COD_ACESSO`, 
`Extent1`.`COD_USUARIO`, 
`Extent1`.`TIPO_USUARIO`, 
`Extent1`.`IP`, 
`Extent1`.`BROWSER`, 
`Extent1`.`PLATAFORMA`, 
`Extent1`.`RESOLUCAO`, 
`Extent1`.`DTH_ACESSO`, 
`Extent1`.`DIA`, 
`Extent1`.`MES`, 
`Extent1`.`ANO`, 
`Extent1`.`HORA`, 
`Extent1`.`URL_ACESSO`, 
`Extent1`.`DISPOSITIVO`, 
`Extent1`.`DOMINIO`, 
`Extent1`.`SUPORTA_ACTIVEX`, 
`Extent1`.`SUPORTA_COOKIES`, 
`Extent1`.`SUPORTA_JAVA_APPLET`, 
`Extent1`.`COORD_LATITUDE`, 
`Extent1`.`COORD_LONGITUDE`, 
`Extent1`.`CIDADE`
FROM `ACESSO` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (`Extent1`.`DTH_ACESSO` >= @p__linq__0) AND (`Extent1`.`DTH_ACESSO` <= @p__linq__1
```

Não sei como proceder para retornar por exemplo itens do mesmo dia entre a horas `22/09/2015 00:00:00` e `22/09/2015 23:59:59`

**Detalhes:** Meu campo já esta como `DateTime` '_.DTH_ACESSO' nao sei como prosseguir!

Comment: você quer pegar independente da hora ?

Comment: Então, quero pegar data e hora. se alguem acessou o sistema ou melhor fez login as 22/09/2015 as 23:58:00 esse dado tem que retornar. quando fizer a consulta 22/09/2015 00:00:00 e 22/09/2015 23:59:59 mas na View tenho campos com DatePicker que so preenchem dia mes e ano entende;

Comment: Faça o teste com a minha resposta `DbFunctions` e me fala se deu certo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [*DbFunctions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx), com o método [TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx):

Independentemente da Hora você quer pegar todos as datas diante o período informado e deve informar ao *Entity Framework* que você só quer pela data (***eu vi pela lógica sua que a hora nessa consulta não precisa***)

Exemplo

```
DateTime dataInicial = DateTime.Parse("22/09/2015");
DateTime dataFinal = DateTime.Parse("22/09/2015");

myDataBaseEntities db = new myDataBaseEntities();

IList<Datas> datas = db.Datas
    .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data) >= dataInicial 
             && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data) <= dataFinal)
    .ToList();
```

SQL gerada por causa do [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[DataJulia] AS [DataJulia], 
    [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data]
    FROM [dbo].[Datas] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Data], 102) ,  102)) >=
    @p__linq__0) 
   AND ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Data], 102) ,  102)) 
   <= @p__linq__1)
```

**Observação:** *Se você mudar a sua regra aonde a data virá completa e você quer pegar pela hora também a sua tela deve ser alterada para aceitar a digitação da hora junto com a data e ai não precisa colocar o* [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx). ***Essa observação é mediante o relato nos comentários.***